# How to remove preview image before upload?

Tags: php

I don't know it don't preview image. I only want to up 1 image, preview 1 image and can remove it. I don't known what error ? so I can't solve, my ability of programming is not good, please help me, Link http://jsfiddle.net/ittvn/h145xey9/19/ Thank all very much.

P/s: I see link http://jsfiddle.net/ERZVC/2/ to make reference

```
function handleFileSelect(input) 
{
    if (input.files && input.files[0])
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function (e)
        {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="',e.target.result, '" title="', escape(e.name), '"/><span class="remove_img_preview"></span>'].join('');
            document.getElementById('preview').insertBefore(span, null);
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: working example `http://jsbin.com/uboqu3/1/edit?html,css,js,output`

Comment: Thank for advuce but I want to make follow it example

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to preview the image, then simply use the function as:

```
function handleFileSelect(input) 
{
    if (input.files && input.files[0])
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh no, I want to preview and remove, similar  http://jsfiddle.net/ERZVC/2/ but it don't a array image, i want only 1 image